# What is it called when the note pattern is the same in each bar but the actual pitch and note are different?

Tags: theory, terminology

[image]I have a question for music theory asking me about what I notice about the rhythm in bars 3-6 and the note pattern is the same : crotchet, 4 quavers, crotchet, minim. But the actual name of the note varies (e.g the first note in bar 3 is an A but in bar 4 it is a G and every note is different like this). There is a particular term for this but I really can't remember it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the intervals are the same also just the starting note is different, that might be sequence.

Comment: Looks somewhat like a fugue subject.

Answer (score 12):

If the melodic contour is similar, either exactly transposed or adjusted to retain the shape but remain diatonic in the prevailing key, it's a [sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_(music)). If the contour of the melody changes, it's a [rhythmic mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmic_mode).

Edit: Now that I see the example, ms.3-6 form a (mainly) diatonic melodic sequence in D minor. I say "mainly", because you get the usual sharping of the leading tone in m.6.

Comment: Another possibility if the rhythms are the same, but the pitches are different could be a rhythmic motif.

Comment: Or a rhythmic ostinato, which is why I'm asking for clarification. The differences between these and rhythmic mode are fairly small, though.

Comment: @Patrx2 - ostinato is something that continues, rather than gets repeated once or twice.

Comment: There are four repetitions in her example, @Tim. Ostinati can be used for small sections of, say, phrase length (as here). In this case, though, we do have a melodic sequence. (It really does look like a fugue subject.)

Comment: @Tim Agreed with Patrx2 here an ostinato is any repeated rhythmic figure.  Also agreed that we have a descending tonal (as opposed to real) melodic sequence.  I have to say though, that the lack of dynamics is kind of bugging me.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes, yeah, I'd expect at least some "resets" of the dynamic levels after the crescendi. If this an opening subject (and it looks to be), its dynamics are "shooting to the top" very early as it is currently notated.